# Why won't chrony sync to GPS when serial data flows through socat?

Tags: gps, socat

I'm using `gpsd` to sync time to a GPS. When I connect my GPS to `/dev/ttyUSB0`, and tell `gpsd` to listen on that port, `chrony` is happy to use it as a time source.

```
gpsd -D 5 -N -n /dev/ttyUSB0
```

However, as soon as I try and pipe that data through `socat` (which is how it needs to work in our production system), `chrony` won't use it as a source. This is the case even though `gpsd`, `cgps`, and `gpsmon` all seem perfectly happy with the GPS data they are getting.

Here's my socat:

```
socat -d -d pty,rawer,echo=0,link=/tmp/ttyVSP0 /dev/ttyUSB0,b4800
```

(my `gpsd` command is the same as above but with `/tmp/ttyVSP0` as the port to listen to in this case).

I'm using `chronyc sources` to confirm when GPS is a chrony source.

My `refclock` line in my `/etc/chrony/chrony.conf` looks like this:

```
refclock SHM 0 refid GPS
```

Answer (score 0):

`pty` ports are prevented from talking to `ntp` (and thus, `chrony`) by an early return meant to prevent code from being executed during testing.

```
void ntpshm_link_activate(struct gps_device_t *session)
/* set up ntpshm storage for a session */
{
    /* don't talk to NTP when we're running inside the test harness */
    if (session->sourcetype == source_pty)
    return;

    if (session->sourcetype != source_pps ) {
    /* allocate a shared-memory segment for "NMEA" time data */
    session->shm_clock = ntpshm_alloc(session->context);

    if (session->shm_clock == NULL) {
        gpsd_log(&session->context->errout, LOG_WARN,
             "NTP: ntpshm_alloc() failed\n");
        return;
        }
    }
```

Discovered thanks to [this bug report](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/gpsd-users/2017-08/msg00009.html)